# Converting Culture Specific Enum DisplayName String to Enum

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've created a small application, which I am now in the process of defining culture specific text for the constants on each of the pages. I've been using a few Enum DropDownLists and have been using the `Display(Name="Something")` attribute for each of the Enum values for the string name to display.

Now that I'm using resource files to determine the text based on the culture I have had to change the attribute values to `[Display(Name="SomeResourceValue", ResourceType=typeof(Resources.Resources))]`

The issue I'm having is that I had a static method that takes the string `DisplayName` and returns the Enum value (providing the Enum type is supplied), which now doesn't work since introducing the resource files.

The method I'm trying to improve upon is as follows:

```
//Converts Enum DisplayName attribute text to it's Enum value 
    public static T GetEnumDisplayNameValue<T>(this string name)
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        if (!type.IsEnum)
            throw new ArgumentException();
        FieldInfo[] fields = type.GetFields();
        var field = fields
                        .SelectMany(f => f.GetCustomAttributes(
                            typeof(DisplayAttribute), false), (
                                f, a) => new { Field = f, Att = a }).SingleOrDefault(a => ((DisplayAttribute)a.Att)
                            .Name == name);

        return field == null ? default(T) : (T)field.Field.GetRawConstantValue();
    }
```

If anyone could help me improve this to allow for a resource lookup I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The working solution is as follows:

```
    public static T GetEnumDisplayNameValue<T>(this string name, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        if (!type.IsEnum)
            throw new ArgumentException();
        FieldInfo[] fields = type.GetFields();

        var field = fields.SelectMany(f => f.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false),
            (f, a) => new { Field = f, Att = a })
            .SingleOrDefault(a => Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(((DisplayAttribute)a.Att).Name, culture) == name);

        return field == null ? default(T) : (T)field.Field.GetRawConstantValue();
    }
```